# registerForRemoteNotificationTypes not working iOS7 xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications, xcode6

I have an issue after upgrading our app to work with iOS 8, where registerForRemoteNotificationTypes does not appear to be working on phone running iOS 7, as in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken does not get called and the "Allow Push Notifications" dialog is not appearing on the app. This is the code I am using

```
// Add registration for remote notifications
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    NSLog(@"iOS 8 Registering for remote notification");
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Registering for remote notification");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

This code works fine for phones running iOS 8, just not iOS 7.
One other bit of information we managed to get push notifications to work on an iOS 7 phone only after running the app through xcode with the phone attached. We then deployed the same code as an ad Hoc deployment to another iPhone and iPad running iOS 7 and neither worked.
Is there something obvious I am missing here.

Comment: `We then deployed the same code as an ad Hoc deployment to another iPhone and iPad running iOS 7 and neither worked` Sounds like your provisioning profiles and push certificates aren't setup correctly. Check the console logs for your device and for your app.

Comment: I am a beginner myself, but shouldn't you place the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; inside of the didRegisterUserNotificationSettings delegate method?  And only if the returned notificationsSettings contains UIUserNotificationTypeAlert?

Comment: The above code goes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. didRegisterForNotifications is triggered by a successful call to registerForRemoteNotifications

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to solve it or understand what is wrong?

Comment: Yes it turned out to be an issue with the provisioning profile generated by XCode. I have a more detailed response below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, may work for you.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions
{
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
// iOS 8 Notifications
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
// iOS < 8 Notifications
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that XCode 6 appears to generate it's own provisioning profiles labeled with XC these also appear in the provisioning profiles of the developer account. When you export the app for ad Hoc release it uses one of these profiles and there appears to be no way to select the profile you created and set in the build setting. It appears it was using a wild card profile that had push notification turned off. I managed to export again with a profile that seemed to be based on one I created with push turn on and it started working. This would explain why I managed to get it to work if I loaded the app directly to the phone from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I got hit the same problem.
In my situation, it turns a simple problem. You should examine your notification setting first.
Going to Setting/Notification Center, and check whether the notification type you set in your code are opened.
Hoping that can help you!

Answer (score 0):

yes the code is very proper,but to get the default notification alert on your device first reset the contents of your simulator and reinstall the app freshly.i tried this and working well on the simulator also.